# modbus control of BLD-300R brushless DC motor controller

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, modbus

I have a BLD-300R generic brushless motor driver, purchased from a chinese webstore. It has a RS485 port for modbus control from a PLC, but I cannot find the protcol specs (baud rate, stop bits, parity, register details etc).

Has anyone used one with modbus that wants to share the connection details?

I realize this is not strictly an *electronics design* question, but this being an component in an electrical panel for an electrical engineering design Im working on, I think I'm asking in the right place.

[image: BLD-300R]

Comment: That is why the advice " buy from a reputable source that supplies ALL the documentation" is so common on here.

Answer (score 1):

Modbus/RTU (ie, over a serial line) has mandatory default settings, per the specification.

- Default data rate of 19.2 kbit/sec.  (Spec 3.2)
- Default format of 8E1 (i.e. 8 data, even parity, 1 stop) (Spec 2.5.1).

[Modbus over serial line Specification v1.02](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf)

Register details are trickier, because register usage is not standardised across controllers.  The best way is of course write to the supplier and ask.

If by chance your manufacturer is ICAN or makes compatible products,
there's a driver called [BLD-300R](https://ican-motor.com/product/bld-300r-bldc-controller-48v-with-rs485/) but I don't see the [manual for it](https://ican-motor.com/manuals/).  There *is* a manual for the [BLDH 400R](https://ican-motor.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/BLDH400R-English-version.pdf), and if you have the facilities, you could see if the software is the same for your driver. Note that other -R suffix drivers from that company have different, but similar, register mappings.

You'll need to be lucky for this to match your device exactly, but it may well be enough to get it going.

Comment: After playing around I found the derault baud is: 9600 8N1

Comment: Modbus addresses:
    **RS485 enable** 0x00B6 (0 or 1)  
    **run** 0x0066 (0 or 1)
    **speed** 0x0056 (0 - 3000)
    **brake** 0x006A (0 or 1)
    **reverse** 0x006D (0 or 1)
    **accel** 0x008A (0-15)
    **alarm reset** 0x0076 (write 0 to reset)

Comment: @MichaelWard does the device have any manufacturer's markings on it?  Glad you found the addresses, seems same as the doc I posted.  Perhaps this is some kind of de facto standard.